# PHP get 00:00:00 of a unix timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql

If I got a unix time which is e.g

```
1407050129
```

How do I get the 12:00AM of that unix day in unix timestamp , means the first minute of the day of that unix time.

Example if i want get today first minute

```
$today_first_min = strtotime("00:00:00");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$that_day = "1407050129";

$that_day_first_min = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $that_day) . ' midnight');
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/TLhXr)

Comment: Its works :) Thanks , will accept in 5 mins when I can accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

An alternate method to arrive at the same result...  Unix time is a count of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, so each whole day is a multiple of (60*60*24) seconds.

Using this fact you can use the [modulus operator (%)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to calculate and then remove the remainder (ie. the seconds, hours and minutes) from the day, and get back to the first hours!

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$that_date  = 1407050129;
$first_hour = $that_date - ($that_date % (60*60*24));

print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strval($first_hour));  

// 2014-08-03 00:00:00
```